# Android Studio - getChildFragmentManager / android-support-v4

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-tabhost

I cannot solve the problem with android-support-v4.

All "Extras" including "Android Support Repository (11)" and "Android Support Library (21.0.3)" - Installed.

I was trying a lot of ideas which I found, but nothing help. I am AndroidStudio beginner. Here is my builg.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
}
```

I want to use TabHost in one of Fragments (I did the Navigation Drawer). That is why I need "getChildFragmentManager()".
If there is another way to do that, I can skip fighting with "support-v4".

But I do not understand I do wrongly... There is a lot of people having this problem, but I can not solve it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I changed manually all "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" in the each place in the application.